# Send Message Over Port 80 Using Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, appfabric, azure-queues, azureservicebus

It seems like the solution to my problem should be easier than it is, which makes me think I'm missing the obvious.  I'm trying to test and ensure that a remote client machine can send/receive messages from an Azure Service Bus Queue.

I'm using the sample application provided by Microsoft at https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/how-to-guides/service-bus-amqp/

The sample application works perfectly fine as long as all ports are open.  However, I need the solution to work when only ports 80/443 are available.  If I configure Windows Firewall to only allow inbound/outbound traffic on 80/443 it doesn't work.  I receive the error "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions".

The offending line from the sample application is:

```
sender = factory.CreateMessageSender(entityName);
```

I've looked at an extraordinary number of sites and one of the suggestions I've found was to set the connectivity mode to Http such as this:

```
ServiceBusEnvironment.SystemConnectivity.Mode = ConnectivityMode.Http;
```

That doesn't work either.

I'm not trying to setup custom services on either the remote client or Azure hosted roles.  I just need them to both be able to send/receive messages via Azure's Service Bus Queues and Topics.

Can anyone point out my flaw?

Comment: I found the answer to why it's not working in my case.  The preview library for AMQP in Azure uses a different port then all other documentation I can find.  Using the release library it works over https automatically.  I'll leave the question open for anyone who can find a way to get the new preview library using AMQP to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment above...

I found the answer to why it's not working in my case. The preview library for AMQP in Azure uses a different port then all other documentation I can find. Using the release library it works over https automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Http Connectivity mode doesnt work for Http 1.0. It will work only on Http 1.1...

If you are in Http 1.0 (mostly proxy) you have to open TCP ports (9350-54)